# How to calculate values in Zapier

Tags: zapier

Hello Trying to calculate values in Zapier and would like some help please. Sorry I'm not a developer.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

The code you posted looks a lot like Python code. The error is that "float is not defined", which is true in Javascript. I'd copy your code, change the step from Javascript -> Python, paste it, and see if that works.

Also, though it may work as written, you should change `input` to `input_data`. The former is deprecated.